# Gtsummary digits by factor levels

Tags: r, gtsummary

How would I go about specifying the number of digits for different levels of a factor in a gt summary table?

For example, in the table output from the code below I would like 0 decimals for Quebec and 1 decimal for Mississippi.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

CO2 <- structure(list(Plant = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
                                   4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                                   5L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
                                   8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
                                   12L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
                                   11L, 11L), levels = c("Qn1", "Qn2", "Qn3", "Qc1", "Qc3", "Qc2", 
                                                         "Mn3", "Mn2", "Mn1", "Mc2", "Mc3", "Mc1"), class = c("ordered", 
                                                                                                              "factor")), Type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                             1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                             2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                             2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Quebec", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                         "Mississippi"), class = "factor"), Treatment = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("nonchilled", "chilled"), class = "factor"), 
               conc = c(95, 175, 250, 350, 500, 675, 1000, 95, 175, 250, 
                        350, 500, 675, 1000, 95, 175, 250, 350, 500, 675, 1000, 95, 
                        175, 250, 350, 500, 675, 1000, 95, 175, 250, 350, 500, 675, 
                        1000, 95, 175, 250, 350, 500, 675, 1000, 95, 175, 250, 350, 
                        500, 675, 1000, 95, 175, 250, 350, 500, 675, 1000, 95, 175, 
                        250, 350, 500, 675, 1000, 95, 175, 250, 350, 500, 675, 1000, 
                        95, 175, 250, 350, 500, 675, 1000, 95, 175, 250, 350, 500, 
                        675, 1000), uptake = c(16, 30.4, 34.8, 37.2, 35.3, 39.2, 
                                               39.7, 13.6, 27.3, 37.1, 41.8, 40.6, 41.4, 44.3, 16.2, 32.4, 
                                               40.3, 42.1, 42.9, 43.9, 45.5, 14.2, 24.1, 30.3, 34.6, 32.5, 
                                               35.4, 38.7, 9.3, 27.3, 35, 38.8, 38.6, 37.5, 42.4, 15.1, 
                                               21, 38.1, 34, 38.9, 39.6, 41.4, 10.6, 19.2, 26.2, 30, 30.9, 
                                               32.4, 35.5, 12, 22, 30.6, 31.8, 32.4, 31.1, 31.5, 11.3, 19.4, 
                                               25.8, 27.9, 28.5, 28.1, 27.8, 10.5, 14.9, 18.1, 18.9, 19.5, 
                                               22.2, 21.9, 7.7, 11.4, 12.3, 13, 12.5, 13.7, 14.4, 10.6, 
                                               18, 17.9, 17.9, 17.9, 18.9, 19.9)), row.names = 1:84, class = c("nfnGroupedData", 
                                                                                                               "nfGroupedData", "groupedData", "data.frame"), formula = uptake ~ 
            conc | Plant, outer = ~Treatment * Type, labels = list(x = "Ambient carbon dioxide concentration", 
                                                                   y = "CO2 uptake rate"), units = list(x = "(uL/L)", y = "(umol/m^2 s)"))

CO2 %>%
  tbl_continuous(
    variable = uptake,
    by = Treatment,
    include = Type,
    statistic = ~"{mean} ({sd})",
    digits = ~1
  )
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please update your post with a minimal reproducible example, aka the minimum data and code that we can run on our machines to illustrate the issue.